# Sublime Text manually specify g++ location

Tags: sublime-text-2, g++

Long story short, I'm using sublime to write some small C++ programs in my spare time. I'm currently on a Windows 7 box and I do not have administrative rights to adjust the Path Environment Variable to point to my portable copy of g++.

Is there a way to manually point sublime to the g++ compiler? I can't seem to find any settings where this would be adjusted.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to edit the build system.

Click *Preferences → Browse Packages...* and open C++ folder, then look for a file called `C++.sublime-build` and open it in Sublime. It should look like this:

```
{
    "cmd": ["g++", "${file}", "-o", "${file_path}/${file_base_name}"],
    "file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
    "working_dir": "${file_path}",
    "selector": "source.c, source.c++",

    "variants":
    [ (...snip...) ]
}
```

In the first line `g++` stands for the command name, you can replace it with a path to g++ executable.

It's worth noting that you can create alternative build systems for other compilers. It's also possible to create build variants (for example to use specific arguments or run the executable after compiling)

Comment: Thanks for that, looks like you can add the custom params then (ex. `-lpthread`, `-lboost_system`).  +1

Comment: This is perfect. I can even choose another compiler if I wish or (as nerdwaller pointed out) change the command arguments. I'm giving you an A+ with distinction